# How to generate a XML file in Excel with data from an external souce?

Tags: sql, xml, excel, odbc

I have to export data from an Oracle database to a XML file. I can retrieve the data in Excel using an MS Query and I can map the cells to a XML schema and successfuly export. The problem is that I have to do it in separeted steps since I cannot map the cells with external link to the XML schema because I get an Error 101311 "The operation can't continue because the result will overwrite an external range or pivot table".

How can I overcome this? Are there another solution to go from ODBC to XML? Thanks.